# Can I use poll and iterate in kafka-python together?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am working with kafka-python. I would like to fetch big amount data from kafka topic till its empty. Then do some action. Then start consuming online new events from that topic. My kafka-python implementation:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'my-topic',
    bootstrap_servers = [my-bootstrap-server],
    auto_offset_reset = 'earliest',
    enable_auto_commit = False,
    value_deserializer = lambda x: json.loads(x.decode('utf-8'))
)
while True:
    x = consumer.poll(timeout_ms = 5 * 1000, max_records = 1000)
    if not x: break
    // some action with x
// consune new events
for y in consumer:
    // some action with y
```

New events are not so often so the 5s poll timeout is ok. Is this design ok? Or there are drawbacks? In the documentation for poll I can see that it is incompatible with iterator interface... See https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.poll

Comment: As the docs say, it is incompatible to use both... Note: `poll` returns a dictionary. Looping over a dictionary will only get the keys (the topics that were polled), not the values. The values of elements in `x` should have the data that you would want in `y`, so you don't need both

Comment: @OneCricketeer maybe I wasn't clear, sorry... my problem is that I want to do some action between polling everything thats is in topic and consuming new events